# Creating maps in R just like the way rworldmap does but for specific country with provinces

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps, rworldmap

I use the `rworldmap` package with WorldBank Data and I enjoy it. I want to plot maps for Iran, with data related to each province. What are the steps to do that? I know we can plot maps like that in `R` for some countries like US but not for all countries.

Comment: You might be better off downloading some GIS shapefile data for Iran and then using one of the spatial packages to plot that in R - see here for the a file that might suit your purposes: http://www.gadm.org/download

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine `rworldmap` with the great suggestion from @jazzurro of using `raster` to get GADM boundaries.

I suspect your main difficulty might be getting the province names to match between your data and the map.

The example below, uses defaults that you can change and just gives a different colour for each province.

```
library(raster)
library(rworldmap)
## 1 Get map of provinces (level 1 admin regions)
iranLevel1<- raster::getData("GADM", country = "Iran", level = 1)

## 2 join your [data] onto the map by specifying the join column in each
## this will report on any mis-matches between province names
#iranLevel1 <- rworldmap::joinData2Map([data],nameMap="iranLevel1",nameJoinIDMap="NAME_1",nameJoinColumnData=[insert])

## 3 plot map (change NAME_1 to the data you want to plot)
rworldmap::mapPolys(iranLevel1, nameColumnToPlot="NAME_1", addLegend=FALSE)

## 4 add text labels for provinces
text(iranLevel1, label="NAME_1", cex=0.7)
```

[image: Iran provinces map using rworldmap and raster]

Note that `joinData2Map()`, `mapPolys()` are more generic equivalents of `joinCountryData2Map()`, `mapCountryData()`.

Another way of doing this would be to use the `choroplethr` package.

Comment: How to change color for specific province?

Answer (score 10):

You can directly import GADM data using the `raster` package. Then, you can draw a map using ggplot2. When you download data, you can specify different level. Depending on this you see different boundaries.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

### Get data
iran<- getData("GADM", country = "Iran", level = 2)

### SPDF to DF
map <- fortify(iran)

### Draw a map
ggplot() +
geom_map(data = map, map = map, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group))
```

[image]

EDIT

Seeing Andy's answer, I'd like to show how to add province names in `ggplot2`. This is something I learned from @hrbrmstr. The `rworldmap` package allows you to type less. The `ggplot2` package still offers very nice graphics as well.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

### Get data
iran<- getData("GADM", country = "Iran", level = 1)

### SPDF to DF
map <- fortify(iran)

map$id <- as.integer(map$id)

dat <- data.frame(id = 1:(length(iran@data$NAME_1)), state = iran@data$NAME_1)
map_df <- inner_join(map, dat, by = "id")

# Find a center point for each province
centers <- data.frame(gCentroid(iran, byid = TRUE))
centers$state <- dat$state


### This is hrbrmstr's own function
theme_map <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
theme(
axis.line=element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),
axis.ticks=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3, "lines"),
axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "lines"),
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),
legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA),
legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"),
legend.key.size=unit(1.5, "lines"),
legend.position="right",
legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.4), face="bold", hjust=0),
panel.background=element_blank(),
panel.border=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
plot.background=element_blank(),
plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.8), face="bold", hjust=0.5),
strip.background=element_rect(fill="grey90", colour="grey50"),
strip.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
strip.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.8), angle=-90) 
)   
}

ggplot() +
geom_map(data = map_df, map = map_df,
         aes(map_id = id, x = long, y = lat, group = group),
         color = "#ffffff", fill = "#bbbbbb", size = 0.25) +
geom_text(data = centers, aes(label = state, x = x, y = y), size = 3) +
coord_map() +
labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Iran Province") +
theme_map()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that GADM's data are not trustworthy!

Comment: How to change color for specific province?

Comment: Could you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970229/custom-color-for-provinces-in-specific-country-using-raster-package-in-r ?