# Add label to provinces to Iran map using plot_geo in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to draw a map, which each province has a specific color. I've gone to [this site](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/administrative-boundaries-1-2) and downloaded the file called "irn_adm_unhcr_20190514_SHP.zip". After I save and unzip it somewhere on my computer then run the following code to produce the below map:

```
iran <- st_read("D:\\rm\\SMI\\www\\gis\\irn_admbnda_adm1_unhcr_20190514.shp")
dat <-data.frame(
id = 1:31,
state = iran$ADM1_EN ,
pr = c(530,-42,1673,75,206,544,1490,118,75,
       40,105,191,111,810, 609,425,418,550, 40, 425, -54,-50,
       16, 18, 133,425, -30, 241,63, 191,100))
dat<-dat %>% mutate(color_province = case_when(pr <= 50 ~ 'green',
                                           pr > 150 ~ 'red',
                                           TRUE ~ 'yellow'))
iran %>% plot_geo(color = ~ADM1_EN,colors=dat$color_province)
```

[image]

How to add province name to this map?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the centres for the provinces and then add them as text.  I've not worked with `plotly` and don't know how to add or format the text, so I've used `ggplot` to show the result.

```
library(tidyverse)

iran <- [point to your shapefile]

labels <- iran %>% 
  filter(ADM1_EN %in% dat$state) %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  st_coordinates() %>% 
  as_tibble()

dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:31,
  state = iran$ADM1_EN ,
  pr = c(530,-42,1673,75,206,544,1490,118,75,
         40,105,191,111,810, 609,425,418,550, 40, 425, -54,-50,
         16, 18, 133,425, -30, 241,63, 191,100),
  x = labels$X,
  y = labels$Y)  

dat <- dat %>% mutate(color_province = case_when(pr <= 50 ~ 'green',
                                                 pr > 150 ~ 'red',
                                                 TRUE ~ 'yellow'))

ggplot(iran) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = dat$color_province)) +
  geom_text(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I must use plotly(plot_geo) instead ggplot!

Comment: I needed `ggplot()` to show the result of extracting the data. You can now use `plotly()` as required. Perhaps, the `add_text()` function.